# SQL recursive query for complex table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I have a pretty complex table structure with parent-child relations.
The idea behind the structure is that some object in child_id can trigger a parent_id.
Assume this data;

Table 1 - map

```
map_id | parent_id | child_id
1      | 1         | 2
2      | 1         | 3
3      | 1         | 4
```

Table 2 - attributes

```
attribute_id | child_id | id_to_trigger
1            | 2        | 5
2            | 5        | 6
```

Example: A questionnaire system is a master. It can contain sub groups to be answered; in which case the sub groups become child of the master. Some answers in the sub groups can trigger an additional sub group within it.

I want to now be able to fetch all the sub group id's for a given master. A sub group can be triggered from multiple sub groups but that isn't a problem since I need just the sub group id's.

As you can tell, master with id 1 has 3 sub groups 2, 3, 4. In the attributes table we can see that sub group 2 can trigger sub group 5; similarly 5 can trigger 6 and so on.

I need 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 in my output. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Yeah I've made the edit with sql-server-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about your design, i suggest that you dont  need 2 tables if you add these 2 recs to your table 1

```
map_id | parent_id | child_id
1      | 1         | 2
2      | 1         | 3
3      | 1         | 4
4      | 2         | 5
5      | 5         | 6
```

you can now use a standard CTE to walk the tree

like this

```
with Tree as (select child_id from table_1 where parent_id = 1
union all 
select table_1.child_id from table_1 
inner join Tree on Tree.child_id = table_1.parent_id)

select * from Tree
```

if you cant change schema this will work

```
with 
table_1 as ( select Parent_id , child_id from map
                union all
                select child_id as Parent_id, id_to_trigger as child_id from attributes)
,Tree as (select child_id from table_1 where parent_id = 1
union all 
select table_1.child_id from table_1 
inner join Tree on Tree.child_id = table_1.parent_id)

select * from Tree
```

Comment: I agree, but a schema change isn't a solution right now. :(

Comment: I have added to the answer if you cant change schema

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT     
    map.parent_id, 
    map.child_id 
    FROM
    map 

    UNION

        SELECT     
        attributes.child_id, 
        attributes.id_to_trigger
        FROM
        map 
        Inner JOIN attributes ON map.child_id = attributes.child_id

    UNION

        SELECT  
        T1.child_id, 
        T1.id_to_trigger   
        FROM
        attributes T1 
        Inner JOIN attributes T2 ON T1.child_id = T2.id_to_trigger
```

Result :

```
parent_id | child_id
1         | 2         
1         | 3         
1         | 4         
2         | 5         
5         | 6
```

Comment: This would work if I knew there are only 2 levels possible. In my case I could go to n levels. :)